# How to show ToolTip only when Text of the Dynamic Size TextBlock is trimmed?

Tags: c#, uwp, tooltip, uwp-xaml, textblock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{x:bind Name}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind ContentHeader.Text,Mode=OneWay}"
                       ToolTipService.Placement="Right" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       Tapped="ContentHeader_Tapped"  >
```

Condition:
My TextBlock's width is determined based on content and I haven't mentioned any width explicitly

Comment: But the converter is solution, which could be reused:)

Comment: Yes but it causes extra overhead which could be eliminated by using Something like behavior. Do post if you have any efficient solution

Comment: Hi, because `Tooltip` does not provide the function of monitoring whether `TextBlock.Text` overflows, we can only use other methods to customize the functions we need, which will inevitably generate additional overhead. Using `IValueConverter` is a good way, even if we don't use it, we still have to judge the rendering overflow of `TextBlock`, this should be an acceptable resource overhead.

Comment: Ok Fine If that is the best way can u post an answer as an example solution please?

Answer (score 1):

The key point of this problem is to complete the conversion by means of the `TextBlock.IsTextTrimmed` property. We can set `Tooltip = null` when `IsTextTrimmed = False`, and set Tooltip to `TextBlock.Text` when `IsTextTrimmed = True`.

We cannot use `ConverterParameter` to pass a changing value (`TextBlock.Text`) because it is a simple object, not a `DependencyProperty`, so we need to create a Converter that can hold the `TextBlock.Text` value.

**Converter**

```cs
public class TrimConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TrimConverter), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool isTrim = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        return isTrim ? Text : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TrimConverter x:Key="TrimConverter" Text="{Binding ElementName=TestBlock,Path=Text}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               x:Name="TestBlock"
               ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=TestBlock, 
                                                Path=IsTextTrimmed,
                                                Converter={StaticResource TrimConverter}}"/>

</Grid>
```

This should solve your problem.

Best regards.

Comment: Bro thanks for the solution but in this case, I can only use this for one text block in a page as you are giving that binding in resource definition itself. How can we use this for multiple text blocks on a single page?

Comment: This is a contradiction, but if we change our mind, you can use this code to create a `UserControl`, and then replace `TextBlock` to it where it is needed.

Comment: Note that there is an open issue on the WinUI team to make this behavior built-in: https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/170. But it's been open for years.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this with the visibility of the `ToolTip`.  Make sure you wrap your tooltip content in a `ToolTip` element:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="ContentHeader"
    Text="{x:Bind Name}"
    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
    ToolTipService.Placement="Right"
    Tapped="ContentHeader_Tapped"
>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding IsTextTrimmed, ElementName=ContentHeader, Converter={StaticResource Converter.VisibleWhenTrue}, Mode=OneWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ContentHeader.Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```